# COUNTIF with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I currently have two sheets, one of which contains user details and the other order details like so:

```
========User Sheet========         =========Order Sheet=========
      A        B      C                 A         B         C
1   UserID | Name | Region         1 UserID | OrderNum |   Date
2      12  |User A|   EU           2   12   |     1    |  MAR-14
3      24  |User B|   US           3   24   |     2    |  APR-14
4      27  |User C|   EU           4   12   |     3    |  APR-14
```

On another sheet, I'd like to calculate the number of orders from a specific region (User!C2:C4) and date (Order!C2:C4).

I know this would be possible by adding a further column to the order sheet with a VLOOKUP, however I'd prefer to do this within a COUNTIFS formula due to the amount of data in the order sheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: When you say "I'd prefer to do this via a formula," what do you mean exactly? VLOOKUP is generally used in a formula.

Comment: Sorry, I meant id prefer to use the vlookup within a countif formula if possible.

Comment: You would have to do a column with your vlookups, and then countif on that.

Comment: If you only want to count the number of orders, why do you need a to lookup something?